# Eclipse Web perspective duplicated

Tags: eclipse

How can I reset the perspectives list ?

As you can see in the following snapshot, `<Web>` (at first) and `Web` (two before the last) are two entries to the same perspective.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete it from the **Perspectives** preference page.

[image: Perspectives preferences panel]

Comment: Thanks! It's too easy! How did I not think of it sooner?